# Getting the exact same results from rand() due to global object being created before main function

Tags: c++, opengl, srand

I am using rand to get some "random" numbers, on Windows, Visual Studio 2010.

In the main file I've included  and  and using this:
`srand(time(NULL))`

And in another file, in the constructor of an object
(*object is defined globally, due to its use in OpenGL functions(Init, Render)*
I am calling rand() % bound, 10 times and getting the same result, both at my laptop and desktop.

This should be due to the object being created before the seeding of rand from main.

How can I avoid that and keep the object being global?

Comment: You _could_ create another global object of a class whose constructor does the `srand` call? Or call `srand` in the existing class constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the constructor of your global object, do `srand(time(NULL))` before using `rand`. Alternatively, have another non-local object with static storage duration that does `srand(time(NULL))`. Make sure it is defined in the same translation unit but before your object that uses `rand`. Non-local objects with static storage duration are initialised in definition order.

Comment: Thank you, this worked fine. So srand is ok to be called from anywhere in one's code, provided that it's called once, right?

Comment: @Chris actually you can call it as many times as you want. You generally never *want* to call it more than once. With the addition of the second half of this answer, you should pursue that route, specifically a static class var.

Comment: Got what you mean with the 2nd route sftrabbit. But will the 1st way (calling srand into the constructor of the object) create a problem?

Comment: @Chris if you have global *array* of that object type, yeah, you have a problem by just firing in the constructor.

Comment: Nope, it's just one object :) Thank you very much for your elaboration on my question as well :)